# Read unicode characters from registry in java

Tags: java

In my Application i am reading registry to get all TimeZone names.
It is working fine with native english OS machine.

But for chinese native os it is showing "????????".

I am using WinRegistry.java, the common file available to read registry in java.

Below is the method that reads bytes from registry, but that bytes contains junk characters only.

```
private static String readString(Preferences root, int hkey, String key, String value)
    throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
    InvocationTargetException 
  {
    int[] handles = (int[]) regOpenKey.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(hkey), toCstr(key), new Integer(KEY_READ) });
    if (handles[1] != REG_SUCCESS) {
      return null; 
    }
    byte[] valb = (byte[]) regQueryValueEx.invoke(root, new Object[] {
        new Integer(handles[0]), toCstr(value) });
    regCloseKey.invoke(root, new Object[] { new Integer(handles[0]) });
    return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
  }
```

In valb[] byte array i am getting the junk characters, so whatever encoding i use to convert that byte array to string, i am getting junk characters only.
Can any one suggest me, what changes in this method will make it work fine??

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309899/converting-byte-to-string

Comment: Where are seeing the question marks? In the console?

Comment: I am retriving the string, and displying it in to a dropdown.
And there in Dropdown i can see that question marks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean [the hack in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163701) that uses a private, undocumented, implementation-specific API.

This code uses the [default encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) to turn the returned bytes into chars:

```
return (valb != null ? new String(valb).trim() : null);
```

On Windows, the default encoding will likely be a legacy encoding - an ["ANSI" code page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752.aspx).

You will need to figure out the encoding of the data and [provide it explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) in the `String(byte[],Charset)` constructor or switch to a documented API - e.g. using [RegQueryValueExW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911.aspx) with [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

*As Octopus pointed out in the comments, it is also easy to turn characters into junk by using `System.out` as it uses lossy legacy encodings too.*

Comment: But i have checked the bytes that i am getting in valb[]. And that bytes it self contains "??????". So whatever encoding we use it will not help..

Comment: Ah, OK. When Java's Preferences API stores Unicode values in the Windows registry it does its own Unicode escaping - it was never intended to be a general registry reader type. WinRegistry.java's hack abuses the internals of this API. This might explain why the array data is corrupt under some locales. I would look at using native code.